# instance_eval's behaviour inside a instance method

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

Below is my snippet which i tried,

```
class Person
  def test(arg)
    self.class.instance_eval do
      define_method(arg) {puts "this is a class method"}
    end
  end
end

irb(main):005:0> Person.new.test("foo")
=> #<Proc:0x9270b60@/home/kranthi/Desktop/method_check.rb:4 (lambda)>

irb(main):003:0> Person.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for Person:Class

irb(main):007:0> Person.new.foo
this is a class method
=> nil
```

Here am adding a method to the Person class dynamically using instance_eval and define_method. But why is this behaving as instance method?.
Is that completely dependent on self?
Confused. Can anyone explain me or a reference link also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [`define_method` defines instance method of the receiver](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method). Your receiver (`self`) is `Person` class, so it defines instance method of `Person` class. You can achieve what you want accessing to `Person`'s metaclass:

```
def test(arg)
  class << self.class
    define_method(arg) { puts 'this is a class method' }
  end
end
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: So even if I use self.class.instance_eval it doesn't matter is it!!??

Comment: But instance _eval also will do the same thing right? it adds the method to meta_clas right?

Comment: No, `instance_eval` executes provided block in the context of the object it was called on (also, it sets 'current class' to be metaclass of this object, but it doesn't matter here, since `define_method` work on `self`). For example, `Person.instance_eval` executes block in the context of `Person` object.

Comment: @Kranthi it's because, like I wrote, `define_method` defines instance method of the receiver (and not of 'current class'). Receiver is `Person`, so it defines instance method of `Person`. 100% agrees with documentation.